# How to find out key-value which matches to given value for a week using mongo?

Tags: mongodb

I have following collection structure -

```
    [{
"runtime":1417510501850,
"vms":[{
    "name":"A",
    "state":"on",
   },{
    "name":"B",
    "state":"off",
   }]
 },
 {
"runtime":1417510484000,
"vms":[{
    "name":"A",
    "state":"on",
 }, {
  "name":"B",
  "state":"off",
 }]
 },{
"runtime":1417510184000,
"vms":[{
    "name":"A",
    "state":"off",
 }, {
  "name":"B",
  "state":"off",
 }]
 },{
"runtime":1417509884000,
"vms":[{
    "name":"A",
    "state":"on",
 }, {
  "name":"B",
  "state":"off",
 }]
 },{
"runtime":1416905084000,
"vms":[{
    "name":"A",
    "state":"on",
 }, {
  "name":"B",
  "state":"off",
 }]
 }
]
```

The difference between these two documents is 5 minutes which is represented by 'runtime'.
I have many such documents.

I want to find names whose state is off for a week. The only condition is state should be off through out week (should not have single value 'on' for key state).

e.g. In above data, if name 'B' is off from one week (by considering 1417510501850 as current timestamp), then my expected output will be -

```
{
 "name":"B",
 "state":"off"
}
```

Currently I am doing following-

1) find documents with state 'off' which are greater than 1 week using (currentTimestamp- 60*60*24*7)
2) Apply loop to result to find name and check state.

Can anybody help to get above output??

Comment: are you using mongoose?

Comment: No. I am trying it on mongo shell

Comment: here runtime is a time stamp

Comment: @SaravananRajaraman yes, it is.

Comment: Do you use your own date integer representation - number of seconds? Why don't you use standard Date objects - that are stored as a 64 bit integer representing the number of milliseconds, as mogo does?

Comment: I am using mongo object now . will update in question also

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the query should  be like this

```
db.yourcollection.aggregate([{$unwind: "$vms"}, //unwind for convenience
{$match: {"vms.state": {$eq: "off"}, runtime: {$lt: Date.now() - 7*24*60*60*1000}}}, //filter
{$project: {name: "$vms.name", state: "$vms.state"}}]) //projection
```

**UPDATE**

This is corrected query to get only docs that didn't have "on" status for a week. It is a bit more difficult, see comments

```
db.yourcollection.aggregate([{$unwind: "$vms"}, //unwind for convenience
{$match: {runtime: {$lt: Date.now() - 7*24*60*60*1000}}}, //filter for a period 
{$project: {_id: "$vms.name", state: "$vms.state"}}, //projection so docs will be like {_id: "a", state: "on"}
{$group: {_id: "$_id", states: {$push: "$state"}}}, //group by id to see all states in array
{$match: {states: {$eq: "off", $ne: "on"}}}, //take only docs which have state "off" and not have state "on"
{$project: {_id: "$_id", state: {$literal: "off"}}}]) //and convert to required output
```

To understand this query it is a good idea to add one by one pipe to aggregate function and check the result.
Hope this helps.

Comment: This query will give me all documents that are poweredOff during given period(may poweredOn in between). I want only such documents which are never powerOn during week.

Comment: Vishwas, I updated my answer to meet your requirements.

Comment: you have given literal at last line as hard coded. what if I have any other key (e.g. 'serialNumber' in json given in question) which is not used for matching or grouping but want as output. How do you get this key in result?

Comment: Vishwas, here you want to get all docs with status "off" so this key is hardcoded not only in last line but also in matching - previous line. I think last line hardcode is not a problem. If you want to output some other key you have to include it in _id key - line 3 - and then get disired output. In this case _id would be combined like this "_id: {name: "$vms.name", serialNumber: ... }".

Comment: If I include it on 3rd line it will group by both id (name) and serialNumber, right?? But I want to group by only id(name).

Comment: Vishwas, but I don't know what docs you have with serialNumber and what output you want to get. You asked here only about state condition. And I gave you an answer. If you now change initial schema and desired output I think it should be another question.